# Code rewrite in Z3 with quantifiers

Tags: arrays, int, z3, assertions, quantifiers

guys

I'm writing a model using Microsft Z3 and I need to add the following assertions to it:

```
(declare-const line (Array Int Int))

(assert (and (> (select line 1) 0) (< (select line 1) 4)))
(assert (and (> (select line 2) 0) (< (select line 2) 4)))
(assert (and (> (select line 3) 0) (< (select line 3) 4)))
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to state is that my 3-length array, called ***line***, can only have elements in [1..3]. This code works perfectly, however, I would like to be able to make these assertions just with a line of code, using quantifiers. I've tried:

```
(assert (forall ((i Int)) (=> (and (> i 0) (< i 4)) (and (> (select line i) 0) (< (select line i) 4)))))
```

Which I though would work... but after executing, Z3 returned unsat, which was't happening with the previous version of the code.

Why is this happening?

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the two versions are equivalent. 
Do you have a full repro (and link to rise4fun.com/z3)?

Comment: yap... I realised the two version were, in fact, equivalent just after submitting the question. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for the comment.